# Advanced PHP settings - selectively including built-in PHP functions

Tags: php, function, settings

There are a hell lot of [inbuilt PHP functions](http://php.net/quickref.php). I was wondering that after almost 2 and a half years of working as a software engineer I hardly use a little fraction of those. But all of them are defined and can be used with the default PHP installations.

I read somewhere in SO that PHP provides all these inbuilt things but doing similar things with languages like JAVA needs a lot of coding. Is that correct? I am not experienced in other languages much.

Also, am I correct to assume that a large portion of these functions are not used by any of the other inbuilt functions or anything (internal dependencies)? E.g. these functions [pdf_fit_table()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-fit-table.php), [gzopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php) are needed only in case of PDF and gzip file related things respectively.

If so, then as advanced programmers, does PHP provide any option to us to selectively load them, based on the specific project requirements or more dynamically, based on a specific  module? e.g. load PDF related functions only if I have PDF related tasks. If possible, at what level can it be done? If at the PHP installation level, then I think it is not possible in case of shared hosting. Is a better solution to this possible?

I am just speaking from a common sense point of view, we include files containing functions on a need basis.

Is it going to give a performance boost?

I am not much aware of the core libraries etc. of PHP. So, please shed some light.

**Updates:**
Thanks for the answers

*@pygorex1*  - The HipHop way is to optimize PHP overall. So, putting in very simple terms, if I am correct, if it was taking 1 second to run before then using HipHop it may make it 0.7 second. But in both the cases, the presence of those extra unnecessary defined functions are adding their overhead (say 0.1 second in first case and 0.07 sec in HipHop case). If so, then HipHop targets something else and does not answer my question. However, the other two points you gave say that all has to be done while compiling. So, it probably means if I compile with an extension then the function groups under that will be loaded every time . Then probably there is no further way of removing the inclusion? Some kind of everride?

*@Tyler* - I agree that it might be difficult to do what I am asking for but the reason is not what you are saying. It cannot be so difficult to find out the dependencies. Just applying common sense, I can say that functions like `is_numeric()`, `is_array()`, `array_walk()`, `func_get_args()` etc. are very basic ones and are probably called by many but there are easily distinguishable groups like the socket functions group containing e.g. `socket_connect()` which need not be included if not explicitly needed. The problem probably is that it needs to be specified while compiling, like pygorex1 has answered.

Comment: someone with a higher reputation please create a tag "inbuilt-functions"

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath - i guess is **built-in** correct me if you think is **in-built**, can you confirm this?

Comment: @ajreal - not sure if there is any difference between them. Depends on what users use often. But SO is autocomplete is smart enough. Creating either will work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.internal.php , this link explain what you eager to find out

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel how is it a lame question? I totally disagree with you!

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - you may be a very good programmer or whatever I don't really care because you need to correct your **attitude** and that is the main thing!! Do you have the solution to my question? Have you found that it is not possible? Why not possible? Or this never occurred in your head? Give some answer. Just saying that it is lame is not going to help anyone. I am not asking a "give me the code to do this" question nor is my explanation unclear!

Comment: The only solution for the stupid questions is just to forget it. Do yourself a favor, forget this stupid idea and learn how to code and profile your code instead.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - Have you really understood what I am asking? I know how to code and profile my code. Why should I forget this before I actually realize that it is not going to work? I am still looking for numeric figures/results to see how is the solution given by powtac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [dl()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) to load a PHP extension at runtime.

**Example to load an extension dynamically:**

```
if (!extension_loaded('sqlite')) {
    $prefix = (PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX === 'dll') ? 'php_' : '';
    dl($prefix . 'sqlite.' . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX);
}
```

This is taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

Answer (score 2):

Concerning any potential performance boost - you're probably not going to notice it unless you're serving a *ton* of dynamic PHP pages. This road has been traveled before - take a look at [HipHop](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358), Facebook's tool to optimize PHP into C++. Utilizing byte code caches like APC and eAccelerator AND/OR rewriting your PHP code to cache intelligently with memcached will improve PHP performance far more than enabling/disabling certain PHP functions.

That having been said, there's two main ways to pare down the number of functions that PHP has available:

**PHP compile-time options**

Available when compiling PHP from source. One of the functions noted in the question `gzopen()` is part of the zlib extension and has to be [enabled at compile time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php). There's quite a few [built-in compile-time options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php).

**PHP modules**

These are loaded dynamically by PHP and are controlled by the php.ini config file under extensions - they are .dll files on Windows or .so files on Linux. A snippet from my development php.ini:

```
...
extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_dblib.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The php function namespace debacle, is, well, exactly that.

No, there's no way selectively load them at run-time. Just because you don't call something, doesn't mean something you call doesn't call it.

Answer (score 1):

Dont bother compiling out built-in functions. Learn about shared libraries and linux caching system. Those files(and functions) are basically always loaded and cached so it has very little impact on an application. As pygorex1 said, its better to use a good caching mechanism than crippling the PHP distribution on purpose.

@powtac: doing `dl()` as a way to dinamically load some libraries might acually slow down your app(depends on how many `dl()` you do, it might be better to have them always loaded in memory than loading them on request)

@Tyler Eaves: you may disable some function from being called actually. There's nothing preventing their loading though..

Also, hip-hop as far as i knwo actually compiles php code down to C/C++ code, and then compiles it. This has the BIG advantage of skipping the virtual machine, and php-specific upcodes and lots of overhead over a scripted language, but has the big disatvantage that its not a scripted language anymore.

Comment: do you have numeric figures/results to prove that the dynamic loading of libraries is slower? or can you post a link?

Comment: @Sandeepan Nath: I dont have the numbers anymore, but its pretty easy to test. I noticed the slowdown with ionCube encoder, as it has(at least ~2 years ago) the option to load the encoder in `php.ini` or as requested by the script, and it used `dl()` in this case(but you didnt't have to touch `php.ini`). Testing with `ab`, the dl() version was something like 20-30% slower that the php.ini version.